# How to Set Route params imperatively in named outlets in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

To set imperatively a route param in a `router-outler` we do:

```
this.router.navigate(['/hero', hero.id]);
```

How do I imperatively set a route parameter in named outlets ?

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets:{modal: 'modal/user'} }]);
```

Right now I concatenate string to set a route param:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {modal: 'modal/user' + '/' + 'this.id'} }]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure your routing file have :id in modal component like this in mine

```
{ path: 'component-aux/:id', component: ComponentAux, outlet: 'sidebar' }
```

and your calling route should be like this

```
id: string="any value you want to set";
this.id= input || 'not set';
```

|| will set default value if no value is specified

```
 <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'sidebar': ['component-aux', this.id] } }]">Component Aux</a>
```

and your aux component should be like this

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-aux',
  template: 'Component Aux'
})
export default class ComponentAux { 
  private id;
  private sub: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  private ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
      console.log(this.id);
    });
  }

  private ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

here is the live plnkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/5aP6MgTRzXr5Urq5fr2J?p=preview  . i hope this will help :)