# Angular2 - Passing params to named outlet

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I need to pass params to a named outlet, from a default outlet. After passing, all I get is 'undefined'. Here is my code.

```
[routerLink]="['', { outlets: { secondOutlet: 'messages' }, name: this.userName, lastName: this.userLastName}]"
```

I receive params with this.

```
    this.route$ = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
     this.name= params['name'];
     this.lastName= params['lastName'];
   });
```

I get no error, but in console, all I get is undefined.
I can send params to a route if it is on the same outlet, but I cant figure out how to do it by sending params from one outlet to another.

Comment: i can see that you have marked answer but there is no clear explanation what was wrong with your code initially?

Comment: @PraveenRawat Wrong was the way of sending params and setting up the route

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { secondOutlet: ['messages', this.userName ] } }]"
```

and in route specification

```
Routes = [
{
    path: 'messages/:username',
    component: AccountsEditComponent,
    outlet: 'secondOutlet'
  }
]
```

Comment: Ok, did that and I can see params in URL. But I still get undefined when receiving them.

 useName: string;
private route$: Subscription;

 this.route$ = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.userName= params['userName'];
    });

Comment: Yes it is, but when receiving the params they show "undefined".

Comment: It is in my first post. I use it all the time and it works, but something does not work now..

Comment: @BrS, you could add FirstChild to your route like this
this.route$ = this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => { this.userName= params['userName']; });

Answer (score 1):

HI can you look at this post

[passing params routed outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42048801/7261317)

i hope it may be helps you

Comment: appreciate your effort but better put it in comment next time onwards

Answer (score 0):

It works like this.
Send params like this:

```
[routerLink]="['', { outlets: { secondOutlet: ['messages', this.username] } }]"
```

And in routes setup your component like this.

```
Routes = [
{
    path: 'messages/:username',
    component: AccountsEditComponent,
    outlet: 'secondOutlet'
  }
]
```

Comment: Mind explaining how this answer is different than the accepted answer?